# Logistic regression on Spark

Tags: apache-spark, logistic-regression

I need to run a logistic regression on Spark. After a little investigation, seems it is included in MLlib. However, it does not give many details of the regression results, such as p-value, confidence interval of the coefficient such as the outputs from R package. Is there any library on Spark that can do that?

Comment: if it is about results rather than the processing itself, you may try to implement it on your own, by writing some routine for processing the output files